# How can I forward a video I received in Facebook Messenger to my email account?

Tags: email, facebook-messenger

How can I forward a video I received in Facebook Messenger to my email account?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it (I have a Samsung and I use Gmail, but the process should be similar with conditions a bit different).

1.
[image: Step 1]

2.
[image: Step 2]

3.
[image: Step 3]

4.
[image: Step 4]